# Why does my table not scale within the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple webpage for homework. The body just consists of various sections div /divbr. The effect is various boxes for each part. Most of my students don't have a computer, they only have a mobile phone. So I am trying to make the webpage display better on mobile phones. I put:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the header.

I set all divs to width:95%;

Everything displays nicely on my phone now. The text is a good size, everything is within the confines of the mobile phone screen, no need to magnify with 2 fingers.

EXCEPT my table.

```css
    .div-table
    {
     width:95%;
     border:3px;
     border-style:solid; 
     border-color:#FF0000;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#32d140;
     
    }
    table
    {
     margin:0 auto;
     width:90%;  
     text-align:center;
     background-color:whitesmoke; 
     border-collapse: separate;
       border: 2px solid black;
      }
    table td {
      /*border: 2px solid black;*/
      border-style:dotted; 
      border-width:3px; 
      border-collapse:separate;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
  <p>
    <table>
      <tr> <td>A watches</td> <td>B cinema</td> <td>C weird</td> <td>D doesn&#39;t</td> <td>E like</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>F games</td> <td>G talking</td> <td>H guy</td> <td>I unusual</td> <td>J teaches</td> </tr> 
    </table>
  </p>
</div>
```

The table spills over its div. You can scroll right a bit to see the last columns. The table was 2 rows of 5 cells. I changed it to 5 rows of 2 cells to get around this now, but  I prefer 2 rows 5 columns.

Why does my table not shrink to fit its div? Could you please help me tweak the css to shrink the table?

Comment: I have googled *Best way to make table responsive on mobile*.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote _ All the Best to you and to your students o: )

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Why are people here often so touchy?

Comment: It's unfortunate isn't it _ Last year Stack Overflow began a new policy about contributors treating each other 'nicely' _ Many of us are trying to do that _ Take Care : )

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can confine the `table` within the `div` and successfully display it at every resolution.

An alternative solution would be to allow the `table` to overflow, thereby making it scrollable:

Adding `overflow-x: auto;` to `div-table` should work for you:

CSS

```
.div-table {
  width:95%;
  border:3px;
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#FF0000;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#32d140;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```css
.div-table {
  width:95%;
  border:3px;
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#FF0000;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#32d140;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

table {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:90%;  
  text-align:center;
  background-color:whitesmoke;    
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table td {
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  border-style:dotted; 
  border-width:3px; 
  border-collapse:separate;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
<p>
 <table>
 <tr> <td>A watches</td> <td>B cinema</td> <td>C weird</td> <td>D doesn&#39;t</td> <td>E like</td> </tr> 
 <tr> <td>F games</td> <td>G talking</td> <td>H guy</td> <td>I unusual</td> <td>J teaches</td> </tr> 
 </table>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not to engage in conversation, but hopefully it's clear that my comment (not rude, just sincere) with the text *"Everything in(*is) on Google already"* means that you can find pretty quickly many ways (on your favorite search engine ;)) topics that speak about responsive table design for mobile. Thank you for removing the w3schools link.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your table is overflowing, to make it neat and clean you can make it responsive. You can either make the table responsive by adding a horizontal scroll, so users can scroll and see the content. You just have to add following styles in media query, You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/fsg8bzr1/5/)

```
  @media (max-width: 767px){
      .div-table{
        overflow-x: auto;
      }
      .div-table table{
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

Or, Other option is stacking it vertically which is bit more user friendly, you can see it [here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Comment: Sorry but *responsive* has nothing to do with adding scrollbars if an element overflows. That's how browsers already behave (eventually) and that's exactly what **responsive UI** fights to abolish and improve.